# Python Data table

Tags: python

I have a data textfile called “data” that is delimited by comma in each row.

The first three lines of the file look like the following:

```
“(1,ABC,ABCDE)”,”24”
“(10,ABD,ABC11)”,”12”
“(6,ABE,ABERD)”,”39”
```

In the file, values in each row are string and integer.

I first read the file:

```
target=pd.read_csv(’data',sep=',',names=[‘col1’,'col2’])
```

What I want to see in my Target table eventually is the following 5 column 
table:

```
COLA  COLB   COLC    col1           col2
1     ABC    ABCDE    (1,ABC,ABCDE)  24
10    ABD    ABC11    (10,ABD,ABC11) 12
6     ABE    ABERD    (6,ABE,ABERD)  39
```

What I tried was:

```
for index,row in target.iterrows():
    tup=tuple(row[0][1:len(row[0])-1].split(","))

    target[’COLA'][index]=tup[0]
    target[’COLB'][index]=tup[1]
    target[’COLC'][index]=tup[2]
```

This is done to change the string to tuple so that I can create new columns to the Target datatable. I will delete the `col1` eventually but the code above doesn't work for some reason. It crashes..

Comment: I tidied up your code formatting, but I noticed that `target[’COLA'][index]=tup[0]` was indented - was this an error in the original question formatting (if so, please edit your question) or is this one source of error?

Comment: @KenY-N error in question formatting! Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of telling us that "the code above doesn't work" and just "crashes," provide as much information you can about what actually happened when you ran the code, including the full traceback (error message). This greatly speeds up the troubleshooting process (and will also help prevent your question from getting closed).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is peppered with "smart quotes": `“”` instead of `"` and `‘’` instead of `'`. Remove them all and replace them with the corresponding straight ("dumb") quotes, as only straight quotes have the Python meaning you're looking for.

Comment: If the code is as shown in the snippet, it won't run properly due to the smart quotes. If new information is added that invalidates this, I'll take appropriate action.